# How Do I Map Ctrl-f To Move Forward A Character In VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have gotten into the habit of using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to move forward a character when staying in insert mode while using the vim mode in various editors. I don't like using the arrow keys or hopping out of insert mode/moving a character with a motion command/getting back into insert mode. How do I make that shortcut work in VS Code? I also often will use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to move backwards a character, but this is less important. I'm open to other suggestions, btw, for moving around while in insert mode without the arrow keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+f",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "right",
    "command": "-cursorRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> opens keyboard shortcuts (or click the gear icon in lower left).
2. Search for cursor right.
3. Mouseover "cursor right", click on "+" or "pen" edit icon.
4. Enter your desired keybinding in the popup dialog, press enter.
5. Vscode will automatically produce the keybindings above in your keybindings.json file.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!